# How to add anchor peers on channel using node sdk hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

How do you add anchor peers to a channel using the node sdk hypereldger fabric? I have created the anchor peer config using `configtxgen` and understand how to add an anchor peer using the cli docker container but would like to be able to accomplish the same thing using the node sdk.

Any help is greatly appreciated- thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have already created anchor peer `.tx` files using `configtxgen`. You may add anchor peer using node sdk by using `updateChannel()` method. Please go through the Fabric node sdk documentation for the same below:-

[Hyperledger fabric node sdk updateChannel()](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Client.html#updateChannel)

Following is the example for the same:-

[updateChannel() example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/app/update-anchor-peers.js#L15)